# How Can I Round Prices to the nearest 0.95 with an Excel Formula?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

I need to round up all my prices to the nearest $0.95. For instance I have 23.106 and 102.58888. They would need to be rounded off to $22.95 and $102.95. How can I do this with an excel formula/function?

Comment: `Round(A1,0) - .05`?

Comment: or `ROUND(A1+.05,0)-.05`

Comment: @BigBen I apologize, I didn't see that.

Comment: If A1 equals 6.98, do you want to return 6.95 or 7.98?

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
 =IF(OR(A3-FLOOR(A3,1)>0.95,A3=CEILING(A3,1)),CEILING(A3,1)+1,CEILING(A3,1))-0.05
```

If the decimal is greater than .95 or is a whole number (no decimals), it will add add 1 to the number and then use the CEILING function to round the number up and then subtract .05.

```
1.52 = 1.95
2.00 = 2.95
66.98 = 67.95
```

Comment: The op did not say round up.  It rounded to the nearest: `23.106` became `$22.95` in the OP's example.

Comment: The very first sentence - "I need to round up all my prices to the nearest $0.95."

Comment: Okay, I will remove the downvote, but you should remove yours on the accepted answer as either could be interpreted as the correct method based on the question.  I will need you to edit your question so I may remove it.  BTW: `=ROUNDUP(A1+.05,0)-.05` will do the same thing but shorter.